# Unable to populate input field value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have been trying to populate a text field in AngularJS for past few days but unable to do so. I am trying to populate this field by the selected value in a abn:tree from a modal window.

While the selection is displayed in modal window but, whenever I try to display it in the parent screen it doesn't do anything.

**View:**

```
<label>Category</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="formControl" ng-model="category" required />
    <span class="groupButton">
        <div ng-controller="ModalCategoryController" >
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="ShowCategory.html">
                <div ng-include="'tpl/category.html'"></div>
            </script>
            <button ng-click="open()">...</button>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="hbox hbox-auto-xs hbox-auto-sm" ng-controller="AbnTreeController">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="wrapper-md">
            <div class="b-a bg-light dk r r-2x">
                <abn-tree
                        tree-data         = "fake_data"
                        tree-control      = "fake_tree"
                        on-select         = "fake_handler(branch)"
                        expand-level      = "2"
                        initial-selection = "Wasif"
                        >
                </abn-tree>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>{{output}}</div>
</div>
```

**Tree:**

Finally my tree is something similar to this:

```
app.controller('AbnTreeController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var fruit_selected, tree, treedata;
    $scope.fake_tree_handler = function(branch) {
      var _ref;
      $scope.result = "selected: " + branch.label;
      if ((_ref = branch.data) != null ? _ref.description : void 0) {
        return $scope.result += '(' + branch.data.description + ')';
      }
    };
    fruit_selected = function(branch) {
      return $scope.result = "apple! : " + branch.label;
    };
    treedata = [
       {
        label: 'Fruits',
        data: {
          bol_value: true
        },
        onSelect: function(branch) {
          return $scope.result = "Fruit: " + branch.data.bol_value;
        },
        children: [
          {
            label: 'Apples',
            children: [
              {
                label: 'Wasif',
                onSelect: fruit_selected
              }]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    $scope.fake_data = treedata;

    $scope.fake_tree = tree = {};
});
```

Whenever I select anything on my tree it displays well in the Dialog but never populate the field **category** which is in parent window.

Comment: Any plunkr or fiddle ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/4GFXChMljrVjiX6eiLln?p=preview add more of your code here.